# How is the core-js library organised in the github repository, definitelyTyped?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I was going through the [core-js](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/core-js/core-js.d.ts) library in the github repository, [definitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and didn't understand the structure of core-js library i.e. it didn't contain all the required methods and properties of different objects such as array, Date. Then I found another file, Date.d.ts which contained the methods and properties for Date. So, my question is how do I find all the properties and methods of different objects such as Date, Array, Function etc.?

Comment: the d.ts files contain only the description of the javascript code. the actual code is transpiled into javascript and will not be found in the definitelyTyped repo.

Comment: I am just looking for the descriptions. The core-js.d.ts doesn't contain description of all methods or properties of the objects. For example, function contains just two methods. That can't be right, right?

Comment: interfaces in typescript are open ended. Most likely the core-js .d.ts files only add the properties missing from the standard declarations.

Comment: then, where could I find the standard declarations?

Comment: well.. a good place to find all declarations for javascript is MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: The thing is that I'm working on a parser for definition typescript files, so I wanted to use definition typescript files from definitelyTyped for that.

Comment: hm.. I think tsc autoimports a file called lib.d.ts that contains everything used by default.. I don't know if you can use that.. or how you could get them merged together.

Comment: But is there any way through which I could use core-js.d.ts from definitelyTyped ?